# Chart JS chart not rendering in ArcGIS popup when using navigation arrows

Tags: javascript, chart.js, arcgis-js-api, esri-javascript-api

I'm putting a chart in the popup of my points. On the initial click, the popups display the chart and if I use the forward navigation arrow on the popup, the next chart renders. However, if I use the back arrow the chart will not render again. The method that generates the charts doesn't seem to be firing the second time. Any help is appreciated. My code is below. Popup:

```
            popupTemplate: {
            title: "{Location}",
            content: [{
                type: "text",
                text: "Sample Location: {Type} </br> Survey: {Survey} </br> {Location:getSurveyInfo} <div id='chartDiv'><canvas id='chartArea{Location}'>{Location:createChart}</canvas></div>"
            },
            {
                type: "attachments"
            }]
        }
```

Chart:

```
    createChart = function (location) {
    var date = new Date();
    var chartArea = "chartArea" + location;
    var sub = location.substring(0, 2);

    getData(date.getFullYear(), [[location]], function (data) {
        var maxScale = Math.max(...data[0].tData);
        var colors = [["#34eb58", "#0000ff"]];
        var chartData = buildChartData(name, maxScale, data, colors, null);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(chartArea);
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, chartData);

    }, getChartDataError)



}
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 4.7 version.

Comment: It looks correct. When you hit back, do you see the previous chart or no chart at all?

Comment: When I hit back, there's no chart at all and if I go forward that chart is gone. I have to hit forward to go to a chart that hasn't been rendered yet to get it to show up.

Comment: One last thing you could try is changing the chartDiv id for a class, maybe it needs to be unique too. Then, can you create a simple jsfiddle that reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to get it working with a different layer since some of this data is private, but having some issues with the mapping in it.

Comment: Ok I'll try to create a jsfiddle too

Comment: Here's a js fiddle I'm attempting. I can't quite get the chart to show up though. http://jsfiddle.net/bspa906m/

Comment: See my edited answer, I think it's the easiest you could do

Comment: I have update your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bspa906m/1/ because `createChart` was not triggered. However, it cannot works because the `canvas` element is not yet added to the DOM when you want to create the chart. `document.getElementById()` return `null`. See my answer instead

Comment: I just updated my answer, there was an error, but I think it works now

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use the text content type for the popuptemplate. Using a function that return HTML element would be easier in your case.

```
    popupTemplate: {
        title: "{Location}",
        content: createPopup
    }
```

here your construct your popupElement and insert chart in it:

```
function createPopup(graphic) {
    try {
        var location = graphic.getAttribute("Location");
        var popupElement = document.createElement("div");
        popupElement.innerHTML = "Sample Location: " + graphic.getAttribute("Type") + "</br> Survey: " + graphic.getAttribute("Survey") + "</br>" + getSurveyInfo(location) + "<div class='chartDiv'></div>"
        var date = new Date();
        var sub = location.substring(0, 2);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        getData(date.getFullYear(), [[location]], function(data) {
            var maxScale = Math.max(...data[0].tData);
            var colors = [["#34eb58", "#0000ff"]];
            var chartData = buildChartData(name, maxScale, data, colors, null);
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, chartData);
         }, getChartDataError);

         popupElement.querySelector(".chartDiv").appendChild(canvas);
         return popupElement;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bspa906m/3/

Comment: I figured it was that at one point as well, and tried appending something unique to the canvas ID and it kept the same result. I tried your code and where the chart should be is just the text [object HTMLCanvasElement].

Comment: ok that's because the popuptemplate expect only text. Can you edit your question to add your try with the unique id

Comment: I can see it working in the JS Fiddle, but can't get it to work in my code. The popup appears cut off in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: verify that you are using this line correctly: `popupElement.querySelector(".chartDiv").appendChild(canvas);` there was an error in a previous version of my answer. Remove the `[0]`

Comment: I still have the same issue even with that.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I was getting no errors and couldn't figure it out. I'll try to work through it and see. I'll update if I figure it out.

Comment: Wrap all your `createPopup` function inside a try/catch and print the error to the console